# macOS MAMP работа с консолью PHP

Tags: macos, консоль, mamp

Всем привет.
Я новичек с macOS.
Я установил MAMP и столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу найти, как мне открыть консоль от MAMP

Я перерыл весь интернет, так и не смог найти.

Никак не могу работать с composer  и т.д!

Comment: Что такое «консоль от MAMP»?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего имеется ввиду консоль OpenServer на Windows, которая сразу содержит установленные инструменты.

Это все PHP, но чтобы на mac использовать php не встроенный, а из MAMP - создайте alias'ы.

https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Languages/PHP/

UPD: в mamp pro в настройках языка под версией языка есть галочка - использовать в консоли (думаю, это проще)